# How to use a QGraphicsWebView?

Tags: html, pyqt

I want to use a QGraphicWebView inside a delegate to render a QTableView cell, but I just don't know what to do with the QStyleOptionGraphicsItem parameter the paint() method requires. How to build it up / where should I retrieve it?
I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959850/how-to-make-item-view-render-rich-html-text-in-pyqt) as reference, so the paint() method should be something like this:

```
def paint(self, painter, option, index):
    web = QGraphicsWebView()
    web.setHtml(some_html_text)
    web.page().viewportSize().setWidth(option.rect.width())
    painter.save()
    painter.translate(option.rect.topLeft());
    painter.setClipRect(option.rect.translated(-option.rect.topLeft()))
    web.paint(painter, ??????) # what here?
    painter.restore()
```

Any advice?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `QGraphicsWebView` as opposed to `QWebView`?

Comment: not really, I assumed it could be a better choice by the fact it has a paint method :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you don't really need `QGraphicsWebView` and that `QWebView` is sufficient.

It's important to keep in mind that you're not expected to call `QWidget::paintEvent()` yourself.  Given that constraint, you'll want to use a helper class that can render on a paint device or render using a given painter. [QWebFrame](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwebframe.html) has one such method in the form of its [render function](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwebframe.html#render).  Based off of your linked-to example, the following should work:

```
class HTMLDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        model = index.model()
        record = model.listdata[index.row()]

        # don't instantiate every time, so move this out
        # to the class level
        web = QWebView() 
        web.setHtml(record)
        web.page().viewportSize().setWidth(option.rect.width())

        painter.save()
        painter.translate(option.rect.topLeft());
        painter.setClipRect(option.rect.translated(-option.rect.topLeft()))
        web.page().mainFrame().render(painter)
        painter.restore()
```

Comment: thank you, my setwidth() part is not really setting the page size, but the render part works good.