# How can I modify a QItemDelegate to support simply text formatting?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to display some items in a QListView with some simple text formatting changes.

My list items are dictionary entries. The word is bold. The definition is not:

- **the word**: the definition
- **another word**: another definition

From reading the documentation, I see I need to create a custom delegate which I started to do but I think I'm doing something wrong. Using QItemDelegate, it looks like there's an awful lot of behavior that I need to replicate for this simple modification.

Is there a way to subclass from QItemDelegate in such a way that I'm not duplicating so much code?

**Edit** after searching some more, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956542/how-to-make-item-view-render-rich-html-text-in-qt)

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended by the [documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qitemdelegate.html#details) to use a QStyledItemDelegate. Easier would be to use a QListWidget and to set the items to QLabels with setItemWidget and to use RichText in the QLabels.