# How can I customize the QCompleter popup window in PyQt?

Tags: qt, pyqt, customization, qcompleter

I have a few things for a QLineEdit's QCompleter I'm interested in customizing. I want to make it behave similar to the address / search bar in Chrome.

1. How can I limit the number of rows that are displayed? For example, even if there are 15 matches, I only want the QCompleter to show 5.
2. How can I resize the popup window? For example, I want to make the popup window nice and snug. As per the above example, I want the popup window to resize to 5 rows exactly without any showing any ugly scroll bars.
3. How can I move the popup window? For example, I want to adjust the vertical position of the popup window so that it's slightly below the parent widget.
4. How can I format the shown popup window's list items? For example, I want to bold the part of the word that is matching.

Comment: QCompleter::setPopup(QAbstractItemView * popup)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. To limit the number of rows: change the model to a
   [QStringListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstringlistmodel.html)
   using
   [QCompleter.setModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html#setModel),
   and set a fixed number of items before the popup is shown. Also ensure that [maxVisibleItems](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html#maxVisibleItems-prop) is set appropriately (default is seven).
2. The popup window should resize to the correct *height*
   automatically. The *width* of the popup can be calculated by adding together the
   width of the margins (`popup.width() - popup.viewport().width()`),
   the width of the frame (`2 * popup.frameWidth()`), and the width of the longest string (`popup.fontMetrics().boundingRect(string).width()`).
3. The positioning (and width) of the popup can be controlled by passing an
   appropriate `QRect` to
   [QCompleter.complete](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html#complete).
4. The format of the list items could be controlled by [setting an item delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setItemDelegate) on the popup. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956542/how-to-make-item-view-render-rich-html-text-in-qt/5443112#5443112) for an example of a rich-text item delegate. (But note that this will effect how the popup width is calculated).

Comment: passing the QRect to the complete method works when it first opens but once the text changes and the popup resizes it reverts to the original position. Is there a way to maintain the offset while editing the text? I tried subclassing the listview and using a move in the showEvent and resizeEvent but it doesn't seem to work very well..

Answer (score 2):

Though I've never tried the Same The Documentation Clearly States to use [`maxVisibleItems(int maxItem)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#maxVisibleItems-prop) to restrict number items visible.

and as with customization of the PopUp Window I thing You need to make a subclass of [`QAbstractItemView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) and pass it on [`QCompleter::setPopup(QAbstractItemView * popup)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#setPopup)

set [`setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop)

Comment: I tried `maxVisibleItems`, and I don't know if it's a mac issue, but it doesn't behave like I thought it would. All it does is resizing the popup window (sort of, it's not exact at all) so you can only see  let's say 5 items. I would expect a popup window resize *and* a cropping in the popup list items too.