# Implementing sizeHint on a QItemDelegate subclass

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I'm trying to create a table where each item contains a pair of rows, like this:

[image]

Ideally, the font of the top row would be different (rather than just bolded.)

My solution is to subclass QItemDelegate and overload `paint` and `sizeHint.`  The above diagram show `paint` working properly, but I haven't been able to figure out `sizeHint`.  Here's what I tried (just doing elements with a single row for now):

```
def sizeHint(self, option, index):
    index_data = index.data(Qt.SizeHintRole)
    if index_data is None:
        return QSize()
    size = QItemDelegate.textRectangle(None,
                                       textLayoutBounds(option),
                                       option.font, str(index_data))
    return size
```

Unfortunately, with PyQt, the protected member function `textRectangle` (called by the default sizeHint) is inaccessible.  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Neither `textRectangle` nor `textLayoutBounds` are public methods of `QItemDelegate`, so you can't use them (obviously). But in any case, what is the purpose of attempting to compute `bottom_size`?

Comment: `index_data` actually contains a list of strings.  I want to calculate a rectangle that is as tall as the sum of the strings and as wide as the widest string.  How should I do that?

Comment: Also, `textRectangle` is protected, so I figured it would be available in a subclass?

Comment: Why do you need to reimplement `sizeHint`? Can you provide some context? The code you've posted gives no clues at all. As for `textRectangle`: you can't access it because it is not part of Qt's public API, and hence not wrapped by PyQt.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I've attached an image showing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I don't have a complete solution to your question. However, for computing text rectangles you could take a look at [QFontMetrics.boundingRect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2). Also, you might be interested in the rich-text item delegate given in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5443112/984421).

Comment: @ekhumoro: Please add that as an answer.  I have decided to make the table have twice as many rows and then fix the headers instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a complete solution to your question. However, for computing text rectangles you could take a look at [QFontMetrics.boundingRect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-2). Also, you might be interested in the rich-text item delegate given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5443112/984421).