# Automatically refreshing a QTableView when data changed

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have written a custom data model to be displayed with several QTableViews.

Technically, everything works fine: my views show the changes made from my model. My data model is editable, and the `setData()` method does emit the `dataChanged()` signal and returns `true` on successful edition.

However, my problem is that I have to move my mouse over a `QTableView` for it to show the actual change, while I would like all views to show the changes when they were made, without needing to interact with the views in order for them to be updated.

Any idea? Thanks,

---

It may be relevant to mention that I do not use the default `Qt::EditRole` role to edit data, but rather a custom enum value (named `ActiveRole`).

Here is what I am seeking: my data model contains properties on how to display data, used to generate style sheets that are fed to the viewS.

Thus, when altering the model, for each view, all its items are impacted, which is why the `dataChanged()` signal is sent with indices covering all cells.

I also tried to emit `layoutChanged()`, but it does not seem to change the behavior in my case.

Here is an excerpt of the `setData()` method:

```
bool DataModel::setData(QModelIndex const& idx, QVariant const& value, int role)
{
  if (ActiveRole == role)
  {
    // Update data...

    QModelIndex topLeft = index(0, 0);
    QModelIndex bottomRight = index(rowCount() - 1, columnCount() - 1);

    emit dataChanged(topLeft, bottomRight);
    emit layoutChanged();

    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here is a sample of the `data()` method:

```
QVariant DataModel::data(QModelIndex const& idx, int role) const
{
  if (ActiveRole == role)
  {
    boost::uuids::uuid id;

    return qVariantFromValue(id);
  }

  return QVariant();
}
```

And `flags()` does indicate an editable model:

```
Qt::ItemFlags DataModel::flags(QModelIndex const& idx) const
{
  if (false == idx.isValid())
  {
    return Qt::ItemIsEditable;
  }

  return QAbstractTableModel::flags(idx) | Qt::ItemIsEditable;
}
```

I have a custom delegate, which relies heavily on this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1956781/948128) for overriding the `paint` and the `sizeHint` methods in order to draw a `QTextDocument`. Also, it provides the content of the `ActiveRole` to the editor in `setEditorData`, and calls `DataMode::setData` in `setModelData`:

```
void DataModelDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget* editor, QModelIndex const& idx) const
{
  auto active = qVariantValue<boost::uuids::uuid>(idx.data(ActiveRole));
  static_cast<DataModelEditor*>(editor)->setActive(active);
}

void DataModelDelegate::setModelData(QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, QModelIndex const& idx) const
{
  auto active = static_cast<DataModelEditor*>(editor)->getActive();
  model->setData(idx, qVariantFromValue(active), ActiveRole);
}
```

In the `createEditor()`, I plug a signal from the editor to a slot of my delegate for committing data:

```
QWidget* DataModelDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, QStyleOptionViewItem const& option, QModelIndex const& idx) const
{
  auto editor = new DataModelEditor(parent);
  connect(editor, SIGNAL(activeItem()), this, SLOT(commitEditorData()));
  return editor;
}
```

When clicking on an item, the editor triggers the `activeItem` signal; the connected slot `commitEditorData` in turn raises the `commitData` signal with the editor in argument.

So all my views use these custom delegate, editor, and data model. The view that I am interacting with does show the change immediately, but the other views need to have the mouse hovering over them to show changes as well.

Comment: Could you show the code of the `setData()` function ?

Comment: So your setData works on custom **ActiveRole** instead of standard **EditRole/DisplayRole**, but what role are you setting to the items? Are you overriding also `data()`? Do you have custom rendering delegate for your view?

Comment: I updated my question with some implementation of data, setData, createEditor and such. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually found the problem, which was that my other view was not properly notified of the data changes: my views each showed different portions of my data, so the other views needed to be notified of the `dataChanged()`, but for their own, proper, indices.

On a side note, I also had the problem of updating my views while my Qt application was not the active window in my window manager. The solution was to call `repaint()` on the main window.

Comment: The solution (calling `repaint()`) didn't work for me.  Furthermore, IMO, the answer is not complete.  Should describe or give example on how to use `dataChanged()` in the code to achive the expected effect.

Comment: This way doesn't always work, call **[layoutChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged)** instead

Answer (score 6):

I have met the same problem, and let me add a detailed explanation to the piwi's answers. If you change the data,and what to update the single or several columns(or rows,depending on your requirement), you should emit a set of index for topleft to bottomright.For example,if you have a table like below:

[image]

and, now you have changed some data, and want to update the cell row 1, column 1-2, then you should emit signal [dataChange](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged)

```
emit datachange(index(1,1),index(1,2));
```

Comment: How can I do it from outside the model?  That is, without the `QModelIndex`es?

Comment: I am too facing same problem, my original table is a non Qt library, and I use it through a qt model and there is no way to get the exact indices of the changed data.

Answer (score -1):

Are you calling the `setData()`? Is the `dataChanged()` signal really emitted? Connect some debug logging slot to it. I dare to speculate that this is very similar problem to yours:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18388-Refreshing-a-QTableView-when-QAbstractTableModel-changes?s=fd88b7c4e59f4487a5457db551f3df2c

Comment: Data is properly changed, `dataChanged` is emitted when needed, within `setData`; changes do show up immediately on the view I am interacting with. The sole problem is that the _other_ view showing same data needs to have the mouse over it to show the changes. I'm prospecting with your link!

Comment: About the link, the problem is that the data model is altered but not through Qt means, thus not emitting the `dataChanged` signal; not my case though :-/

Comment: How can I do it from outside the model? That is, without the `QModelIndex`es? I can't make `QModelIndex`es from integer indexes because the constructor is private.