# In Pyqt/PySide How to set different color in on cell of the TableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I get data from database and show it on a TableView.

In one cell some keywords should be more obvious to the user like warnning critical and so on.

I know how to change the font color of the whole cell's words but this we just need to red some of them.

e.g.

**warnning**: Your trial period is only **20** days left

The words warnning and the number 20 should be color in red the other words should be black as normal.

How to?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a [model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) for your table view, which returns for some cells red foreground color for role [`ForegroundRole`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum). Something like:

```
class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole and condition_for_red_color:
                return QtGui.QBrush(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a delegate to achieve what you want - the standard views don't support that sort of text formatting.

The delegate can paint the cell any way you want.  It's not as hard as you might think but it will require you to create a paint method that writes the text in the two colours.  Ideally you would want it to support all the general styling so make it a subclass of QStyledItemDelegate.  Here are some good examples which cover everything you need:

[How to make item view render rich (html) text in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956542/how-to-make-item-view-render-rich-html-text-in-qt)

UNfortunately there's currently a bug in the PySide implementation of `QStyledItemDelegate.initStyleOption`:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/PYSIDE-115

which can cause some difficulties with getting the style exactly right.  But red text should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes here for **how to make negative numbers red** in a table, warvariuc's answer just about nailed it. Here's pyqt code if it helps anyone (it should make any negative numbers red and everything else, including strings or non-numbers, black):

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):    
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data
    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole:
                try:
                    if np.float(index.data()) < 0:
                         return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
                    else:
                         return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
                except:
                    return QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
```