# QTreeWidgetItem display html

Tags: html, qt, pyqt, qtreewidgetitem

I would like to have a QTreeWidgetItem display formatted html.(PyQt)
Has anyone successfully managed this?

```
htmlString = r"<b>BoldText:</b>SomeValue"
item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem( item, [htmlString], 0)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to set up a custom delegate. See discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956542/how-to-make-item-view-render-rich-html-text-in-qt

Answer (score 4):

to answer my own question:
I created a widget containing a QTextEdit and used setHtml() to display htmlString
Then added this widget to the tree:

```
anItem = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem( parentWidgt )
parentWidgt.setItemWidget(anItem, 0, widgContainingTextEdit)
```

Cheers!