# Modal dialog edition in a QListView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlistview, qitemdelegate

I'm a beginner with QT/PyQt4, and I'm trying to make a `QListView` display custom objects.

It should :

1. Have custom row widgets that display more than one line of text, possibly images
2. Trigger a modal dialog instead of the inline edit field whenever I double-click on an item

A `QItemDelegate` seems like the right choice, but I can't figure out how to use it properly for either #1 or #2. Any ideas?

Comment: Will the images be placed within text or into a separate column?

Comment: No separate columns. I just want to display additional information within the same row, without making it a full table view. A little like Android's Preference screens or, for example, the Transmission UI (http://www.johnoriordan.ie/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Transmission_web_interface.png).

Comment: Multiple types of data in a single "cell"... Maybe HTML is the answer? In that case this link could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956542/how-to-make-item-view-render-rich-html-text-in-qt  - look for the answer which describes doing it in PyQt

Comment: You mean [this](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/richtext-html-subset.html)? So I could just write something like `<strong>My Title</strong><br/>Additional information` and it would render correctly in the `QListView`? Damn, that's pretty sweet, I'll give it a try and let you know if it worked!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Good luck!

Comment: QStyledItemDelegate cannot display HTML. You need to create or use a custom delegate, like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956542/how-to-make-item-view-render-rich-html-text-in-qt

Comment: I think that's exactly what @AlexVhr linked to earlier, but thanks ;)