# How to format QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

There is a big tree. Its items are `std::string` including text colors indexes after null symbols.

For example

'\0'0Red Text'\0'1 Green Text'\0'0 Red Text'\0'2 Blue Text

I need to paint text it QTreeWidget items with several colors in an each item. There is very desirable to don't recreate items every time when the tree updates.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1956781/1034253

This is works but I am afraid that tags adding may require much time.